# How can I read an hex number with dlmread?

Tags: matlab, file, parsing, csv, octave

I'm trying to read a `.csv` file with Octave (I suppose it's equivalent on Matlab). One of the columns contains hexadecimal values identifying MAC addresses, but I'd like to have it parsed anyway, I don't mind if it's converted to decimal.

Is it possible to do this automatically with functions such as `dlmread`? Or do I have to create a custom function?

This is how the file looks like:

```
Timestamp, MAC, LastBsn, PRR, RSSI, ED, SQI, RxGain, PtxCoord, Channel: 26
759, 0x35c8cc, 127, 99, -307, 29, 237, 200, -32
834, 0x32d710, 183, 100, -300, 55, 248, 200, -32
901, 0x35c8cc, 227, 100, -300, 29, 238, 200, -32
979, 0x32d6a0, 22, 95, -336, 10, 171, 200, -32
987, 0x32d710, 27, 96, -328, 54, 249, 200, -32
1054, 0x35c8cc, 71, 92, -357, 30, 239, 200, -32
1133, 0x32d6a0, 122, 95, -336, 11, 188, 200, -32
```

I can accept any output value for the (truncated) MAC addresses, from sequence numbers (1-6) to decimal conversion of the value (e.g. `0x35c8cc -> 3524812`).

My current workaround is to use a text editor to manually replace the MAC addresses with decimal numbers, but an automated solution would be handy.

Comment: have you tried [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html)?

Comment: @Shai I'm looking at it, but if I understand it will decode the strings as text, whereas I want to get the values along the other numbers. Perhaps I could use it in a separate file as a workaround.

Comment: `fscan` has a `%x` format to read hexa numbers...

Comment: @clabacchio: "decode the strings as text" - dont understand what you mean with this and what output you expect.

Comment: @Daniel I'm trying to get a matrix as output, from a csv file that has all columns with decimal numbers and only one containing some MAC addresses, therefore hex values

Comment: @clabacchio: So you are expecting strings for the mac-addresses and doubles for all decimal fields? hex values is not a data type.

Comment: @Daniel in the question I clarify that I don't mind having the hex converted to decimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions `dlmread` and `csvread` will handle numeric files. You can use `textscan` (which is also present in Matlab), but since you're using Octave, you're better off using `csv2cell` (part of Octave's io package). It basically reads a csv file and returns a cell array of strings and doubles:

```
octave-3.8.1> type test.csv
1,2,3,"some",1c:6f:65:90:6b:13
4,5,6,"text",0d:5a:89:46:5c:70

octave-3.8.1> plg load io; # csv2cell is part of the io package
octave-3.8.1> data = csv2cell ("test.csv")
data = 
{
  [1,1] =  1
  [2,1] =  4
  [1,2] =  2
  [2,2] =  5
  [1,3] =  3
  [2,3] =  6
  [1,4] = some
  [2,4] = text
  [1,5] = 1c:6f:65:90:6b:13
  [2,5] = 0d:5a:89:46:5c:70
}
octave-3.8.1> class (data{1})
ans = double
octave-3.8.1> class (data{9})
ans = char
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>> type mycsv.csv
Timestamp, MAC, LastBsn, PRR, RSSI, ED, SQI, RxGain, PtxCoord, Channel: 26
759, 0x35c8cc, 127, 99, -307, 29, 237, 200, -32
834, 0x32d710, 183, 100, -300, 55, 248, 200, -32
901, 0x35c8cc, 227, 100, -300, 29, 238, 200, -32
979, 0x32d6a0, 22, 95, -336, 10, 171, 200, -32
987, 0x32d710, 27, 96, -328, 54, 249, 200, -32
1054, 0x35c8cc, 71, 92, -357, 30, 239, 200, -32
1133, 0x32d6a0, 122, 95, -336, 11, 188, 200, -32
```

You can read the file with csv2cell. The values starting with "0x" will be automatically converted from hex to decimal values. See:

```
>> pkg load io % load io package for csv2cell
>> data = csv2cell ("mycsv.csv");
>> data(2,1)
ans =
{
  [1,1] =  759
}
```

To access the cell values use:

```
>> data{2,1}
ans =  759
>> data{2,2}
ans =  3524812
>> data{2,5}
ans = -307
```